How should I unite shapes using Paper.js?
I have the following code, but it does not match the expectations of a paper.io like game. It fills new areas, but not correctly. The player should return to the original base and the base is not expanding. What can I do? The Paper.js's unite method is not good either, because it leaves holes in the base.
I mean something like this on the picture. The white shapes should be filled as well:



paper.setup(document.getElementById('gameCanvas'));

const player = new paper.Path.Circle({
    center: paper.view.center,
    radius: 5,
    fillColor: 'red'
});

let base = new paper.Path.Rectangle({
    point: [paper.view.center.x - 50, paper.view.center.y - 50],
    size: [100, 100],
    fillColor: 'lightblue'
});

let destination = player.position;
let drawing = false;
let playerPath;

paper.view.onMouseMove = function (event) {
    destination = event.point;
};

paper.view.onFrame = function (event) {
    const vector = destination.subtract(player.position);
    if (vector.length > 1) {
        vector.length = 1;
        player.position = player.position.add(vector);

        if (!drawing && !base.contains(player.position)) {
            // Start drawing when moving out of the base
            drawing = true;
            playerPath = new paper.Path({
                segments: [player.position],
                strokeColor: 'lightblue',
                strokeWidth: 2
            });
        } else if (drawing) {
            playerPath.add(player.position);

            // Check if the path intersects with the lightblue areas
            const intersections = base.getIntersections(playerPath);
            if (intersections.length > 0) {
                // Complete the path
                drawing = false;
                playerPath.add(intersections[0].point); // Optional: refine to add intersection point
                playerPath.closed = true;
                playerPath.fillColor = 'lightblue';
                playerPath = null; // Reset the path
            }
        }
        player.bringToFront();
    }
};
canvas {
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.12.11/paper-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="gameCanvas"></canvas>




When you say that it's not working correctly, do you mean something like this? If I understand the game correctly, the expanded base should have triggered the filling. As it is now, the expansion only happens if the red circle is returned to the original square base.
